# Using a CNAME record to point to an Amazon ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I have an elastic load balancer in an AWS VPC.

I can access the resources successfully behind the load balancer exposed on different ports - standard https 443 and a couple of higher ones say 8888.

So

https://aws-elb.xxxxxxxxxxxx.region.com:443
https://aws-elb.xxxxxxxxxxxx.region.com:8888

all work - I get the expected security warning but can ignore and access the service.

I then added a CNAME record for *mysite.example.com* to point at https://aws-elb.xxxxxxxxxxxx.region.com and got a cert for mysite.example.com.

Now I can access

https://mysite.example.com[:443]

successfully, but

https://mysite.example.com:8888

times out.

I was under the impression that the CNAME would just route through to the underlying url and all would work?

Answer (score 1):

That's weird, DNS has *nothing* to do with the port you're connecting to (443, 8888).

Are you sure you're testing it from the same place? Does the ELB security group permit connection to `8888` from your location?

Or is it perhaps not *timeout* but instead *some other error* that you're facing on `8888`?

Comment: Turns out the dns provider only proxy a couple of non standard ports. The request was never making its way to the elb (found that it by turning on the logging and seeing only 443 was getting hit).

Comment: @PaulB DNS translates host names to IP addresses, nothing else. It’s got *nothing* to do with *ports*. Really. From your location try the ALB address on port 8888 and the hostname on port 8888 and see what it does. Even if there is a problem it’s got nothing to do with DNS.

Comment: @PaulB Like I said - it’s got nothing to do with DNS and everything to do with CloudFlare port forwarding ;) It would have been useful if you had mentioned that you’re using CloudFlare as that’s a whole extra layer between your clients and your site.

Comment: Appreciate your help ... I had no idea a CNAME had anything to do with port forwarding ... thought it was just an alias to url - hence no mention of Cloudflare.